# What is a good noun to refer to somebody who is unhappy?

Tags: word-request, nouns

What nouns can be used to refer to somebody who is unhappy and would complete the following sentence?

> the ... lost his wife and his job

*The unhappy*? *The unfortunate*? Or is it *the unhappy one* or *the unfortunate one*?

Comment: "The unfortunate man"?

Comment: @KateBunting possible... https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+unfortunate+man+lost%2Cthe+poor+man+lost%2Cthe+poor+thing+lost&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20unfortunate%20man%20lost%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20poor%20man%20lost%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20poor%20thing%20lost%3B%2Cc0 "the poor man" is better, though.

Comment: I thought of "sad sack", but "unhappiness" apparently isn't the primary descriptive meaning I've always understood.  According to search results, the primary meaning of "sad sack" is much more strongly about ineptitude than happiness.

Comment: It doesn't work in your sentence but "Emo" is a modern colloquial term that fits the other requirement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[unhappy](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unhappy)** cannot be used as a noun. **[unfortunate](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unfortunate)** can and sometimes is used, but a noun phrase like "poor man", "poor thing" or "poor soul" is more widely used.

**[wretch](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wretch)** can also be used, but it passed its "best before" date in about 1930. It is still used, but mainly as a literary device in historical novels or in religious texts.

This [Ngram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+poor+soul+lost%2Cthe+poor+thing+lost%2Cthe+poor+man+lost%2C+the+unfortunate+lost&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20poor%20soul%20lost%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20poor%20thing%20lost%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20poor%20man%20lost%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20unfortunate%20lost%3B%2Cc0) shows that **poor man** is a clear favourite at the moment.

Comment: *"Leduc, as is true of many **other unhappies**, is largely a confessional writer"* from [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unhappy): unhappy (plural unhappies) = An individual who is not happy.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko.. I hadn't though of looking for plurals... neat idea. There's a reference in John Irving's "The world according to Garp".. "Occasional unhappies were picked up by the police". Unfortunates is uncommon, but unhappies is about 2000 times less common.

Comment: @JavaLatter what about "the unhappy" (as if referring to all unhappy people)?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko now that's a lot closer. "the unfortunate are" is roughly twice as common as "the unhappy are". They are, however, 200 and 400 times less common than "the poor are".

Comment: Note that using adjectives as nouns this way generally refers to a large class of people. You wouldn't normally use them to refer to a specific individual as in the question.

Comment: Interesting find, nonetheless. Is the usage of "unhappies" based on artistical freedom, or on established rules?

Comment: Just asking considering you appear to know more that me, would the one with bad luck fit?

Comment: @user1934212 google NGrams finds several old occurences of "unhappies", but when you look at the original documents, they seem to be mis-scanned, for example "Unhappy is Edward" (Marlowe) was scanned as "Unhappies Edward". The more recent instances are real, so I would suspect artisitic licence.

Comment: @DragonairGirl "the one with bad luck" is rather verbose... "the unlucky one/man" might work though.

Answer (score 8):

The word for a miserable person is a *[wretch](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wretch)*. However it is fairly rare, and has a sense of "someone in rags in Victorian novel". It would have slightly hyperbolic meaning:

> The wretch lost his wife and his job.

It collates as "the poor wretch".

Note that "wretch" can also mean "a despicable person"

Comment: The only answer with an unambiguous noun.

Answer (score 4):

English *mostly* does not like to use adjectives as nouns referring to concrete things such as people or objects. Most of the time when adjectives get used directly as nouns, they are being used either as abstract nouns (usage of ‘fun’ as a noun mostly fits this) or as collective nouns for a group of people or objects that share that quality (for example ‘the dispossessed’, note that this usage almost exclusively requires the use of either the definite article (‘the’)).

When you’re talking about something or someone specific (as is the case here), you almost always need to attach the adjective to a noun. When the intent is simply to indicate that it’s a person or object with that quality, the norm is to use as generic of a noun as possible for the resultant noun-phrase. For people, this usually means either a generic such as ‘person’ or ‘man’, or the use of the formal generic pronoun ‘one’.

In your case, I would probably use ‘man’ or ‘woman’ here unless I was trying to sound *very* formal, in which case I would use ‘one’. ‘Unfortunate’ also fits a bit better with the rest of the sentence than ‘unhappy’ unless you are trying to emphasize the end-result.

---

The one major exception to the above explanation is that you can sometimes (in very informal speech) use an adjective directly with a determiner such as ‘this’ or ‘that’. Only some adjectives work this way, so it’s not something you will commonly encounter in practical usage of English, but it’s important to know that it *can* be done in some cases to avoid confusion if you do encounter it.

---

Also, strictly speaking, the word ‘wretch’ can be used in this specific case, but it’s rather uncommon in modern vernacular (that is, you will not come across many people using it outside of  very formal situations), and it has an alternative usage for referring to someone who is horrible or despicable in some way, which can lead to ambiguity if you use it (especially since that second meaning seems to be the dominant one in some dialects). Even if it’s not ambiguous though, it still has a strongly negative connotation for a lot of people which the use of something such as ‘unfortunate one’ or ‘unhappy man’ does not have (at least not to the same degree).

Answer (score 0):

The **unlucky one** the **unfortunate one** or the **one with bad luck** I think would fit well.